# xcode call a method with just self

Tags: iphone, methods

I'm french so excuse me for my English. SO I have a method, but I don't want that this method is being called when the view appears and just want that to be called when I do a self. How can I do this please ?

Comment: Can you show us some code? I'm afraid your question is a little bit hard to understand.

Comment: @Jamie: in an Objective-C method, `self` is a pointer to the instance that reveived the method call. Essentially the same thing as `this` in C++.

Comment: "when I do a self" - self is not a method, it is an object.  You do not do self.  You do things TO self.

Comment: What do `animation` and `timer` have to do with this question?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for init? maybe?

```
-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
        //do something here
    }
    return self;
}
```